# How do I show a location on the map using latitude-longitude data? (Android Application)

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, dart

I'm working on an android project. I want to add a map about the museum the user wants to get information about. The region marked on this map should show the location of that museum. But in the code I wrote below, latitude and longitude data only belong to a museum. But I want to get latitude and longitude information from SQLITE and define it for all museums.

This is the code snippet:

```
LatLng _center = LatLng(36.54371283052991, 31.98871188028454);

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("111"),
        position: _center,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkconnection.checkConnection();
    onAddMarkerButtonPressed();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the screenshot of my android project:

[image]

And, this is the DB Browser for SQLite :

[image]

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look this package **'geocoding'.**

https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding

I hope it works.